# Select from selected node return data all xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

There is XML with settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <TablesConfig>  
      <Logs>
        <Table name="T_1" key="id">
          <FieldsSearch>
            <Field>All</Field>        
          </FieldsSearch>
          <LinksDetail>
            <Link table="t_Det11" key ="id" srcKey="id_request" sortField ="id"/>
            <Link table="t_Det12" key ="id" srcKey="id_request" sortField ="id"/>
            <Link table="t_Det13" key ="id" srcKey="id_request" sortField ="id"/>      
          </LinksDetail>
        </Table>
        <Table name="T_2" key="id">
          <FieldsSearch>
            <Field>All</Field>        
          </FieldsSearch>

          <LinksDetail>
            <Link table="t_Det21"  key ="id" srcKey="operid" sortField ="id"/>
            <Link table="t_Det22" key ="id" srcKey="operid" sortField ="id"/>      
          <Link table="t_Det22"   key ="id" srcKey="operid" sortField ="id"/>
          </LinksDetail>
        </Table>
  </Logs>
</TablesConfig>
```

In my code in TableSettings I select one node, in getFiltersList I want get list from FieldsSearch selected node, but node.SelectNodes("//FieldsSearch/Field") return 2 Rows. why?
Can I select one node and work with it?

```
Class TableSettings{
    XmlNode node;
    public TableSettings(string TableName) {
                doc = new XmlDocument();
                tabSettingsPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\ExtFiles\\TablesConf.xml";
                doc.Load(tabSettingsPath);
                node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Table[@name='"+TableName+"']"); 
            }
            public List<string> getFiltersList() {
                List<string> filtersList = new List<string>();
                foreach (XmlNode inNode in node.SelectNodes("//FieldsSearch/Field")) {
                    filtersList.Add(inNode.FirstChild.Value);
                }
                return filtersList;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path // is started from the root.
For Work with currentnode need use .// - start with current node ".//FieldsSearch/Field"
or use just "FieldsSearch / Field"

```
public List<string> getFiltersList()
{
    List<string> filtersList = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode inNode in node.SelectNodes(".//FieldsSearch/Field"))
    {
        filtersList.Add(inNode.FirstChild.Value);
    }
    return filtersList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the child nodes of your selected node but all descendant nodes from root. You can correct it as:

```
public List<string> getFiltersList(XmlNode node)
{
    List<string> filtersList = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode inNode in node.SelectNodes("FieldsSearch/Field"))
    {
        filtersList.Add(inNode.FirstChild.Value);
    }
    return filtersList;
}
```

Comment: my misstake node is global var in class. When i check innerXml in Debug  i see correct xml with one table in node

Comment: @dMazay, it doesn't matter global or local, you were not searching its children nodes. Anyway, it is also better not to use such a variable at top level but pass as a parameter.

Comment: At first I Call TableSettings then  getFiltersList And node  Already will be initialized